# App Store submission minimum app version, could it be 0.9.0?

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

I've submitted my iPhone app for review to Apple.

It is now in the state "Waiting for review".

I am afraid having set the version of the app to 0.9.0 could be a reason for rejection:

http://venturebeat.com/2013/02/08/9-surprising-reasons-mobile-apps-get-rejected-from-the-apple-app-store/

Has anyone experience this?

Should I take the shot or resubmit my app and restarting the queue?

Comment: As per my knowledge your app may get rejected because of this.But better you wait and watch for their review.As know days you can see they accept some apps with minor bugs.Hope for best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been accepted with version number 0.9.0

https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/mobeye/id672720804?mt=8